# How can I get a key in a JavaScript 'Map' by its value?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a JavaScript 'Map' like this one

```
let people = new Map();
people.set('1', 'jhon');
people.set('2', 'jasmein');
people.set('3', 'abdo');
```

I want some method to return a key by its value.

```
let jhonKey = people.getKey('jhon'); // jhonKey should be '1'
```

Comment: Then why did you store it the wrong way round? :-P

Comment: Why do you need to question a requirement?

Comment: @Bergi Probably because he also needs to access it the other way around.

Comment: I would suggest something different than the top answers posted here. Rather than iterating which costs CPU, store another map which is an inversion. You could create a wrapper class with convenience methods and use it for read/write ops on the 2 maps.  Memory is cheaper than CPU.

Comment: I landed here with the exact same issue. Questioning the requirement made me think of my implementation. Turns out storing the other way around was the simplest solution since it won't require extra processing (loops).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could convert it to an array of entries (using `[...people.entries()]`) and search for it within that array.

```js
let people = new Map();
people.set('1', 'jhon');
people.set('2', 'jasmein');
people.set('3', 'abdo');
    
let jhonKeys = [...people.entries()]
        .filter(({ 1: v }) => v === 'jhon')
        .map(([k]) => k);

console.log(jhonKeys); // if empty, no key found otherwise all found keys.
```

Comment: @Rajesh, actually, we need the key, not the index.

Comment: Actually we need the key not the index or value.. :)

Comment: @NinaScholz I am curious, are you really using this kind of one-liners in your job, and whether you are debugging your code in any way?

Comment: @Engineer, in this case, i would use a different data structure, not a map. but the code is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @NinaScholz You don't need the array access and `||` logic if you destructure the map values directly: `[...people.values()]`

Comment: @philraj, i changed the answer. anothher solution could be the use of `Array.from` with a mapping of the value.

Comment: @NinaScholz weird, I didn't know about that trick. [edit] What's the `{ 1: v }` syntax? You're destructuring the key value pair as an object? Why not `[k, v]` instead

Comment: @philraj, it's an array for destructuring. and if you have an element at a certain index, you could use the index for destructuring with an new variable.

Comment: This should not be the answer, it returns the value by searching for the .... value

Comment: @JohnB, right. but now it searches all values and return an array of keys. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer because it unnecessarily creates an array. See my answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 78):

You can use a `for..of` loop to loop directly over the map.entries and get the keys.

```js
function getByValue(map, searchValue) {
  for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    if (value === searchValue)
      return key;
  }
}

let people = new Map();
people.set('1', 'jhon');
people.set('2', 'jasmein');
people.set('3', 'abdo');

console.log(getByValue(people, 'jhon'))
console.log(getByValue(people, 'abdo'))
```

Comment: One advantage to this solution is possibly speed, as there is no array transform.  To really get into the spirit of ES6 though, might be nice if you change the `var` to a `const`..

Comment: Nice one,. just a heads up `const` works here too in `for of`.  It's doesn't work like a normal `for` in this regard.

Comment: Just my personal preference to use `let` over `const`.

Comment: You don't need the `map.entries()`, the map itself acts as an iterator. I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 18):

Though late and other great answers already exist, still you can give the below "..." and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) a try:

```js
let people = new Map();
people.set('1', 'jhon');
people.set('2', 'jasmein');
people.set('3', 'abdo');

function getKey(value) {
  return [...people].find(([key, val]) => val == value)[0]
}

console.log('Jasmein - ', getKey('jasmein'))
console.log('Jhon - ', getKey('jhon'))
```

Comment: but what if you want O(1) lookup in both directions

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Given a JavaScript Map, I like [Nitish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135661/how-can-i-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-map-by-its-value/53313763#53313763):

```js
// JavaScript Map

const map = new Map([
  [1, 'one'],
  [2, 'two'],
  [3, 'three'],
]);

function getKey(val) {
  return [...map].find(([key, value]) => val === value)[0];
}

console.log(getKey('one'));   // 1
console.log(getKey('two'));   // 2
console.log(getKey('three')); // 3
```

For a JavaScript object, you could do something like this:

```js
// JavaScript Object

const map = {
  1: 'one',
  2: 'two',
  3: 'three',
};

function getKey(val) {
  return Object.keys(map).find(key => map[key] === val);
}

console.log(getKey('one'));   // 1
console.log(getKey('two'));   // 2
console.log(getKey('three')); // 3
```

Comment: nice, for the Map one in order to not error if the value match is never found and just return undefined instead, the function can be `[...map].find(([key, value]) => val === value)?.[0]`

Comment: Which one is performance optimized one ([...map].find or map.foreach) ?

Answer (score 10):

There isn't any direct method for picking out information in this direction, so if all you have is the map you need to loop through the set as suggested by others.

If the map/array/other is large enough that such a loop would be a performance issue and the requirement for a reverse lookup is common within the project, you could implement your own structure using a pair of maps/arrays/other with one as per the current object and the other with the key and value reversed.

That way, the reverse lookup is as efficient as the normal one. Of course, you have more work to do as you need to implement each method that you need as a pass-through to one or both of the underlying objects so if the map is small and/or the reverse lookup is not needed often the scan-via-loop option is likely to be preferable due to being simpler to maintain and possible simpler for the JiT compiler to optimise.

In any case, one thing to be wary of is the possibility that multiple keys could have the same value. If this is possible then when looping through your map you need to decide if you are fine to return one of the possible keys arbitrarily (probably the first one) or if you want to return an array of keys, and if implementing a reverse index for data that could have duplicate values the same issue also needs to be accounted for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a properly typed Typescript solution that doesn't unnecessarily create an array.

```js
function find_map_value<K, V>(m: Map<K, V>, predicate: (v: V) => boolean): [K, V] | undefined {
  for (const [k, v] of m) {
    if (predicate(v)) {
        return [k, v];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

If you want all values you can use a generator:

```
function* find_all_map_values<K, V>(m: Map<K, V>, predicate: (v: V) => boolean): Generator<[K, V]> {
  for (const [k, v] of m) {
    if (predicate(v)) {
        yield [k, v];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This only returns the _first_ matching entry. If more than one key maps to the same target value, those other matching keys will be ignored.

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you want them all just change `return` to `yield` and update the return type appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

One could invert the Map so that the keys are the values and the values are the keys and then lookup the original value as a key. Here's an example:

```js
let myMap = new Map([
  [1, 'one'],
  [2, 'two'],
  [3, 'three'],
]);

let invertedMap = new Map([...myMap.entries()].map(
  ([key, value]) => ([value, key]))
);

console.log(invertedMap.get('one'))
// => 1
```

Comment: but what happens when the value is a duplicate?

Comment: @Brooklyn99 Using duplicate values as keys is problematic given keys require uniqueness. However, even in this case the `invertedMap` will reflect the value of the last of the duplicate values.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply make use of map's built in [`iterator` prototype/instance reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) looking for the target value? Injection into the prototype chain/polyfill inspired solution of sorts makes it universal to ones code:

```js
Map.prototype.getKey = function(targetValue){
  let iterator = this[Symbol.iterator]()
  for (const [key, value] of iterator) {
    if(value === targetValue)
      return key;
  }
}

const people = new Map();
people.set('1', 'jhon');
people.set('2', 'jasmein');
people.set('3', 'abdo');

const jhonKey = people.getKey('jhon');
console.log(`The key for 'jhon' is: ${jhonKey}`);
```

For anyone curious why I added yet another answer. Most of these answers (exception, I like [Rajesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136047/1992129), but I added to the prototype chain) are doing a lot of data duplication in the name of finding a value by using the spread operator or even straight up crafting Arrays. Object.keys() mind you is also terribly nonperformant.

Note, I use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which iterates on iterables. One could do short hand simply with `for(const [key, value] of this){...}` if desired.

Comment: Having result variable outside the forEach iteration doesn't feel great to me - the result should be const, the key that is found is const. Answer by @Timmmm seems like a better version.

Comment: @oldwizard -- I updated per your feedback, please note the answer you referenced is typescript and the question is tagged for javasript.

Answer (score 1):

Tailing off what [Maciej Krawczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135661/how-can-i-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-map-by-its-value#comment131116052_47135661) suggested here is a general circular map implementation for that.

```
class ReferenceMap {
  #left = new Map();
  #right = new Map();

  constructor(iterable = []) {
    this.#left = new Map(iterable);
    this.#right = new Map(ReferenceMap.swapKeyValues(iterable));
  }

  has(key) {
    return this.#left.has(key) || this.#right.has(key);
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.#left.has(key) ? this.#left.get(key) : this.#right.get(key);
  }

  set(key, value) {
    this.#left.set(key, value);
    this.#right.set(value, key);
  }

  delete(key) {
    if (this.#left.has(key)) {
      let ref = this.#left.get(key);
      this.#left.delete(key);
      this.#right.delete(ref);
    } else if (this.#right.has(key)) {
      let ref = this.#right.get(key);
      this.#right.delete(key);
      this.#left.delete(ref);
    }
  }

  entries() {
    return this.#left.entries();
  }

  keys() {
    return this.#left.keys();
  }

  values() {
    return this.#left.values();
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.entries();
  }

  get size() {
    return this.#left.size;
  }

  static * swapKeyValues(entries) {
    for (let [key, value] of entries) yield [value, key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My TypeScript version:

```
const getByValue = <A, B>(m: Map<A,B>, searchValue: B):[A, B] | undefined => {
  const l:IterableIterator<[A, B]> = m.entries();
  const a:[A, B][] = Array.from(l);
  return a.find(([_k,v]) => v === searchValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cache

The question is a bit wrong because one value can be assigned to many keys. Therefore, the result for a given value should be an array of keys (not a single key). If you want to oftet make such search you can use following cache generator for reverse map

```js
let genRevMapCache = map => [...map.entries()].reduce((a,[k,v]) => {
  if(!a.get(v)) a.set(v,[]);
  a.get(v).push(k);
  return a;
}, new Map() );
```

```js
let genRevMapCache = map => [...map.entries()].reduce((a,[k,v]) => {
  if(!a.get(v)) a.set(v,[]);
  a.get(v).push(k);
  return a;
}, new Map() );


// TEST

let people = new Map();
people.set('1', 'jhon');
people.set('2', 'jasmein');
people.set('3', 'abdo');
people.set('4', 'jhon');

let cache = genRevMapCache(people);

console.log('jasmein', cache.get('jasmein'));
console.log('jhon', cache.get('jhon'));
```

Answer (score -1):

JS:

```
// Returns keys for all instances
function findAll(obj) {
  return Array.from(items.keys()).map(k => items.get(k) === obj ? k : undefined).filter(k => k);
}

// Returns keys for the first instances
function findFirst(obj) {
  return Array.from(items.keys()).find(k => items.get(k) === obj);
}
```

Typescript:

```
protected items = new Map<TKey, TObject>();

public findAll(obj: TObject): Array<TKey> {
  return Array.from(this.items.keys()).map(k => this.items.get(k) === obj ? k : undefined).filter(k => !!k);
}

public findFirst(obj: TObject): TKey | undefined {
  return Array.from(this.items.keys()).find(k => this.items.get(k) === obj);
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
// Gets the keys as an array
Array.from(this.items.keys())

// Map the keys whose object matches the instance of `obj` to the key itself, undefined otherwise
.map(k => this.items.get(k) === obj ? k : undefined)

// Filter out array elements that are undefined
// (!! is for strict type-checking/readability practices, you can simply use k => k)
.filter(k => !!k)

// Finds the first occurrence of the key for the given object, undefined if not found
.find(k => this.items.get(k) === obj)
```